# init of an EList

Tags: java, emf

To avoid adding problem with which value should I init the value of rule_prio ? ...1) rule_prio.add(int x , Rule r) doesn't work too; 2)initializing it with an existing EList doesn't work too 3) is temp.remove(int) is really deleting the value or modify only the pointer ????

```
    private static EList<Rule> priorite(EList<Rule> R) {

        Rule r;
        int min ;
        int p=-1;
        int last_p = -1;
        EList<Rule> rule_prio = null; 
        EList<Rule> temp = R;

        while(temp.isEmpty()==false)
        {
            min=temp.get(0).getPriority();
            for (int i=1; i<temp.size(); i++)
            {
                r = temp.get(i);
                if (r.getPriority() < min)
                {
                    min = r.getPriority();
                    p = i;
                }
             }
    if (p!= -1 && p!= last_p)
    {  
        rule_prio.add(temp.get(p));
        temp.remove(p);
        last_p = p;
    }

}
    return rule_prio;
  }
```

Or it could be rule model the problem ?

Comment: What is an "EList"? And which line exactly causes the NPE to be thrown? Have you tested the variables on that line to find out which one is null? Do you know the general principles of how to debug NPE's?

Comment: show your stacktrace and show, what line of code caused the NullPointerException

Comment: the line rule_prio.add(temp.get(p)); and no i don't anything about debugging NPE's

Comment: EList ...Ecore List, all type prefix are E..., EFloat, EInt ....

Answer (score 2):

> ***is the initial value null of rule_prio the problem***

for sure it is... if you declare

```
EList<Rule> rule_prio = null;
```

and then do this:

```
rule_prio.add(temp.get(p));
```

it makes sense that you get a NPE...

you have to init the **EList** how ever that object is initialized...

```
EList<Rule> rule_prio = ...//init the EList here;
```

Comment: this is the problem it must be empty

Comment: I tried to init it with R but with that adding become impossible from 0 without removing which means i will lose position of pointer .....(can't be more clear i'm not a good english speaker)

Comment: I dont know what EList is, but rule_prio must be initialized before you try to put something in it....